# Split column csv pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to separate the data in 1 column into several columns,

```
"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "T", "Height"
```

The file I have is like the following image

[image]

Comment: use ```sep=' '``` when you read in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
headers = ["Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "T", "Height"]
df = pd.read_csv('station-56003-wget.csv',sep=' ',names=headers)
```

Comment: Did it work? in splitting it into columns?